# cloned hard drive failed

Tags: hard-drive, clone

I cloned my drive to replace it with a higher capacity (from 1 TB to a 2TB) , replaced it, it worked properly for a week or so, then it failed, so I went back to the original drive. I'm now leery of cloning it again for any reason: could the software used have been the reason for the failure? I'm stumped.

Comment: No, the cloning software has nothing to do with a drive failure after a week or so.

Answer (score 0):

> could the software used have been the reason for the failure?

The answer is Yes, but only very very indirectly.

The disk you bought was already in a bad shape if the writing to it of
less than 1 TB caused it to fail after a week.
Disks are usually rated for doing much *much* more than 1 TB in their lifetime.

I suggest using the warranty to replace the disk. Although the quality of
any disk one buys is purely a matter of luck, I would be careful with
using another identical disk.

You should really look at the cloning as a good acceptance test for the new disk,
rather than as a danger.